# laravel 4 app in subdomain and subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I have a domain structure that setup so I can easily add new projects/experiments by using this url labs.domainname.com/[app-name]

with this apache configuration

```
ServerName labs.domainname.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/labs.domainname.com

<Directory /var/www/labs.domainname.com/>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews Indexes
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

it works for simple projects but I have yet to be able to figure out how to make it work for a L4 project. Can this configuration work for what I'm trying to do without having to make a new virtual host file for every project? and yes mod_rewrite is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

By default  Laravel will expose its **public** folder to server, which represents entry point into Laravel application.  So you will have to change document root to:

```
 **var/www/your_project_path/public/**
```

You can modify that behaviour, but that is common settings.